# Performance issues Once more than one client has connect to server

Tags: java, sockets, server, datagram

I am currently working on a multiplayer java game. To allow multiple clients to play at the same time I have created a `DatagramSocket` server.

The "protocol" for my server works something like this:

1. Client send update to server.
2. Server receives update.
3. Server creates a new thread to process the update.
4. The new thread sends a packet back to the client containing what needs to be rendered.

The 4th step is achieved by using the following method:

```
public void sendBack(InetSocketAddress address, ArrayList<RenderEntity> renderEntities) {
    Player p = this.clients.get(address);
    RenderPacket packet = new RenderPacket(renderEntities, p.getX(), p.getY());
    this.byteBuffer = packet.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(this.byteBuffer, this.byteBuffer.length, address.getAddress(), address.getPort());
    try {
        this.socket.send(sendPacket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This "protocol" works relatively well from what I have tested on my own machine, but from what I have seen online the 4th step of my "protocol" is unconventional. Once an update has been received a packet containing what needs to be rendered is sent to **all** of the clients connected to the server as apposed to **just the client that sent the update**.

To try and implement this change I tried using the following method:

```
public void sendToAll(ArrayList<RenderEntity> renderEntities) {
    try {
        for (InetSocketAddress address : this.clients.keySet()) {
            Player p = this.clients.get(address);
            RenderPacket packet = new RenderPacket(renderEntities, p.getX(), p.getY());
            byte[] data = packet.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address.getAddress(), address.getPort());
            this.socket.send(sendPacket);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `sendToAll(renderEntities)` method works great when just one client is connect but as soon as another client connects the client experiences many performance issues and I don't know why. I believe that the the problem is not related to the server because it is still able to communicate with the clients.

What are some possible reasons as to why are there performance issues when more than one client is connected to the server?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it is a DatagramSocket (java.net.DatagramSocket)

Comment: Add logging to your server (e.g. slf4j + logback) and include the thread name in the log. Then you may be able tu understand better which thread is performing which actions and where the performance issue comes from.

Comment: Sorry about that confusion, and thank you for the clarification. Have you profiled the code to find out where the bottleneck is? It's hard for us to diagnose without a [mcve].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No I have not profiled the code but I plan to soon. Sorry for making it unclear, and I forgot to mention that the DatagramSocket used by the server thread to send the packets is the same one used to receive packs, should I be creating a new Datagram socket specifically to send data?

Comment: @Robert great idea, I’ll try that.